# How to create inward curve with edge crease?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow, subdivision-surface

I build the hull and use a subdivision surface modifier.
I know that if I want to sharpen an angle on the outside, to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

But how can I sharpen that angle so that is inward?
As you can see in the picture, there is a curve. I have tried but can't find a solution.

I would like to remove the curve in the picture and turn it into an angle.
I am grateful if anyone can tell me how to do it!

[image]

Comment: You have a concave face, + an N-Gon, both are not so great when using subdivision surface modifier. Is it better if you add a creased edge there ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPeSu.png (Use J to join the 2 vertices, not F)

Comment: Indeed. I got the desired result using F.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

This face is an N-Gon which notoriously doesn't bode well with subdivision surface, and it is concave, meaning there is an interior angle > 180°, which also can create artifacts.

By joining the 2 vertices with <kbd>J</kbd> or *Vertex > Connect Vertex Path* and increasing the crease on the new edge, you will be able to make the subdivided mesh adhere more to the base mesh.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPeSu.png]

Although you now have a triangle to get rid of, but this is another topic :)

Answer (score 2):

To keep your topology clean, you can model the shape as if there were no cutout and use a vertex group with a mask modifier to remove the section.

For this example, I added the two selected vertices to a new vertex group by pressing <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**G**</kbd> and then selected that group in the mask modifier. At first, the mask modifier will hide the part of the model that isn't in the group, but by clicking the <kbd>**↔**</kbd> button on the modifier, it will invert the group weights, hiding the correct vertices.
[image: hull]

Keep in mind that any vertices that neighbor unhidden ones will still affect you final geometry's curvature.